# Gmail Draft (HTML with Attachment) with MimeKit, C# Winforms and Google API

Tags: c#, winforms, google-api, gmail, mimekit

I am attempting to generate a Gmail draft message in a winforms application using C#. The draft message needs to be in HTML format and able to contain an attachment.

I was able to generate a draft with an attachment using `AE.Net.Mail`, but the draft message was in plain text (I couldn't figure out how to code `AE.Net.Mail` to give me an HTML Gmail draft message).

In an attempt to get the message into an HTML format I used MimeKit to take a `System.Net.Mail` message and convert it into a `MimeMessage` message. However, I cannot figure out how to get the MIME message into in an RFC 2822 formatted and URL-safe base64 encoded string as required by the Gmail draft specification.

**Here is the code from the MimeKit Conversion attempt**:

```
var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
});

MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(); //System.Net.Mail
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
msg.Subject = "HTML Email";
msg.Body = "<a href = 'http://www.yahoo.com/'>Enjoy Yahoo!</a>";
msg.Attachments.Add(file);

MimeMessage message = MimeMessage.CreateFromMailMessage(msg); //MimeKit conversion

//At this point I cannot figure out how to get the MIME message into 
//an RFC 2822 formatted and URL-safe base64 encoded string
//as required by the Gmail draft specification
//See working code below for how this works in AE.Net.Mail
```

**Here is the code using `AE.Net.Mail` that works, but generates the body of the Gmail draft as plain text** (based on [this article](http://jason.pettys.name/2014/10/27/sending-email-with-the-gmail-api-in-net-c/) by Jason Pettys):

```
 var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
 {
     HttpClientInitializer = credential,
     ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
 });

 var msg = new AE.Net.Mail.MailMessage //msg created in plain text not HTML format
 {
     Body = "<a href = 'http://www.yahoo.com/'>Enjoy Yahoo!</a>"
 };

 var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
 AE.Net.Mail.Attachment file = new AE.Net.Mail.Attachment(bytes, @"application/pdf", FileName, true);
 msg.Attachments.Add(file);

 var msgStr = new StringWriter();
 msg.Save(msgStr);
 Message m = new Message();
 m.Raw = Base64UrlEncode(msgStr.ToString());

 Draft draft = new Draft(); //Gmail draft
 draft.Message = m;

 service.Users.Drafts.Create(draft, "me").Execute();

 private static string Base64UrlEncode(string input)
 {
     var inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
     // Special "url-safe" base64 encode.
     return Convert.ToBase64String(inputBytes)
       .Replace('+', '-')
       .Replace('/', '_')
       .Replace("=", "");
 }
```

Is there a way to convert MimeKit's `MimeMessage` message into an RFC 2822 formatted and URL-safe base64 encoded string so that it can be generated as a Gmail draft? Failing that, is there a way to create an `AE.Net.Mail` message in HTML format prior to encoding it? All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have several posts about Drafts API Gmail. did you tried download Draft or Message in EML format?

Comment: @Kiquenet you asked a question in a previous comment below this question, I answered in a reply comment, and then both were deleted. (Perhaps by you?) Now you post the above question in a comment. My question in this post was resolved more than a year ago. I do not know why you are asking further questions about whether or not I tried the EML format. My questions have been answered. I did post three different questions. Two were answered and one remains open (which I should close and will put on my to do list). Thank you for your interest, but I no longer need help with this specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way of doing what you want is something like this:

```
static string Base64UrlEncode (MimeMessage message)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream ()) {
        message.WriteTo (stream);

        return Convert.ToBase64String (stream.GetBuffer (), 0, (int) stream.Length)
            .Replace ('+', '-')
            .Replace ('/', '_')
            .Replace ("=", "");
    }
}
```

but a more efficient way of doing this would require implementing our own UrlEncoderFilter to replace your ".Replace (...)" logic:

```
using MimeKit;
using MimeKit.IO;
using MimeKit.IO.Filters;

// ...

class UrlEncodeFilter : IMimeFilter
{
    byte[] output = new byte[8192];

    #region IMimeFilter implementation
    public byte[] Filter (byte[] input, int startIndex, int length, out int outputIndex, out int outputLength)
    {
        if (output.Length < input.Length)
            Array.Resize (ref output, input.Length);

        int endIndex = startIndex + length;

        outputLength = 0;
        outputIndex = 0;

        for (int index = startIndex; index < endIndex; index++) {
            switch ((char) input[index]) {
            case '\r': case '\n': case '=': break;
            case '+': output[outputLength++] = (byte) '-'; break;
            case '/': output[outputLength++] = (byte) '_'; break;
            default: output[outputLength++] = input[index]; break;
            }
        }

        return output;
    }

    public byte[] Flush (byte[] input, int startIndex, int length, out int outputIndex, out int outputLength)
    {
        return Filter (input, startIndex, length, out outputIndex, out outputLength);
    }

    public void Reset ()
    {
    }
    #endregion
}
```

And the way you'd use this is like this:

```
static string Base64UrlEncode (MimeMessage message)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream ()) {
        using (var filtered = new FilteredStream (stream)) {
            filtered.Add (EncoderFilter.Create (ContentEncoding.Base64));
            filtered.Add (new UrlEncodeFilter ());

            message.WriteTo (filtered);
            filtered.Flush ();
        }

        return Encoding.ASCII.GetString (stream.GetBuffer (), 0, (int) stream.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Makes perfect sense to pass the `MimeMessage` and write it to a stream. I ended up using my "replace" logic as I was not able to get the `UrlEncoderFilter` to work. All HTML I attempted to place in the email body did not encode correctly and was placed as strings of gobbledygook. If time allows I will work on this some more to see if I can figure out where I am going wrong. Very much appreciate your help and thank you for creating MimeKit!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the C# code I used to create a gmail draft with an attachment...

```
using System;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace SendStatusReportsAddin1
{
    class Program
    {
        // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
        // at ~/.credentials/gmail-dotnet-quickstart.json
        //static string[] Scopes = { GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly };
        static string[] Scopes = { GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom };
        static string ApplicationName = "Gmail API .NET Quickstart";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Authorization
              UserCredential credential;

              using (var stream =
                  new FileStream("client_secret2.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
              {
                  string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                      System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                  credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials3/gmail-dotnet.json");

                  credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                      GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                      Scopes,
                      "user",
                      CancellationToken.None,
                      new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                  Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
              }

            //Create Gmail API service.
              var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
              {
                  HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                  ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
              });

            //Create mail message
              MailMessage mailmsg = new MailMessage();
              {
                  mailmsg.Subject = "My test subject";
                  mailmsg.Body = "<b>My smart message </b>";
                  mailmsg.From = new MailAddress("joe.blow@hotmail.com");
                  mailmsg.To.Add(new MailAddress("jeff.jones@gmail.com"));
                  mailmsg.IsBodyHtml = true;
              }

            //add attachment
              string statusreportfile =
                        @"C:\Users\ey96a\Google Drive\10 Status-Vacation-Expense\Status Reports\UUM RewriteStatus Report.pdf";

              Attachment data = new Attachment(statusreportfile);
              mailmsg.Attachments.Add(data);

            //Make mail message a Mime message
              MimeKit.MimeMessage mimemessage = MimeKit.MimeMessage.CreateFromMailMessage(mailmsg);

            //Use Base64URLEncode to encode the Mime message
              Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message finalmessage = new Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message();
              finalmessage.Raw = Base64UrlEncode(mimemessage.ToString());

            //Create the draft email
              var mydraft = new Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Draft();
              mydraft.Message = finalmessage;

              var resultdraft = service.Users.Drafts.Create(mydraft, "me").Execute();

            //Send the email (instead of creating a draft)
              var resultsend = service.Users.Messages.Send(finalmessage, "me").Execute();

            //Open the SendStatusReports form
              aOpenForm.myForm1();

        }  //end of Main

        //Base64 URL encode
        public static string Base64UrlEncode(string input)
        {
            var inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
            // Special "url-safe" base64 encode.

            return System.Convert.ToBase64String(inputBytes)
                .Replace('+', '-')
                .Replace('/', '_')
                .Replace("=", "");
        }

    } //end of class Program

}
```

Comment: How find ***draft*** and send it ?

Answer (score 0):

> Failing that, is there a way to create an AE.Net.Mail message in HTML format prior to encoding it?

You can try

```
msg.ContentType = "text/html";
```

in your AE.Net.Mail.MailMessage